# Need Help with Simple JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I need help with javascript. I need to create a hidden input with the name "keywords", and write a JS function that populates it with the values of the checked checkboxes when the form is submitted.

---

First, I had to change the "," to a "|" because that is the correct syntax for ExpressionEngine. But for some reason the search will not work if there is a "|" at the end.

So for example if I select three checkboxes the output to the hidden keyword box is Aberdeen|Harrisburg|Avon| and this will not work with the search, but if I manually enter Aberdeen|Harrisburg|Avon with no "|" at the end, the search will work.

So How can I change this line to not have a "|" at the end of the keywords
templateValues += checkBox.value + "|";

Comment: Do you use a JavaScript library?

Comment: Why? The information about which checkboxes are checked is already sent to the server (since the checkboxes will submit that data themselves). This just duplicates effort (and is less reliable since it adds a dependency on JavaScript).

Comment: Why I need it is because I am using ExpressionEngine search and to search multiple terms I need to the JavaScript to dynamically put the checked checkbox values in the keyword search in expressionengine. If that makes any sense

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<form action="sdmlsurvey.com/search/eresults"  method="post" onsubmit="populateTemplateValues()">
            <script type="text/javascript">
                function populateTemplateValues()
                {
                    var checkBoxes = document.getElementsByName("template");
                    var len = checkBoxes.length;
                    var templateValues = "";
                    for(var i=0; i<len; i++)
                    {
                        var checkBox = checkBoxes[i];
                        if(checkBox.checked)
                        templateValues += checkBox.value + "|";
                    }
                    document.getElementsByName("keywords")[0].value = templateValues.replace(/\|$/g, "");
                    alert(document.getElementsByName("keywords")[0].value );// Remove this in actual script. This is just for demo.
                    return true;
                }
            </script>
            <input type="hidden" name="keywords" value=""/>
            <input type="checkbox" name="template" value="1"/> 1<br/>
            <input type="checkbox" name="template" value="2"/> 2<br/>
            <input type="checkbox"  name="template" value="3"/> 3<br/>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
        </form>
```

Comment: Except inline scripts and `onsubmit` properties are superceded idiomatically by a proper external script file and programmatic DOM element hooks using `document.getElementById()`.

Comment: Sorry for being such a newbie where do I put form action <form action="http://www.sdmlsurvey.com/search/eresults" method="post">

Comment: You got it right except for the ; after the action value. Remove that.

Comment: But where in you sample/demo do I put that "form action"

Comment: @Tomalak Inline JavaScript is OK, inline vs. external depends on the scenario. However, onevent attributes are suboptimal, since we want to separate the JavaScript code from the markup.

Comment: @Christopher: Updated the post to reflect the action attribute.

Comment: Can you look at my website sdmlsurvey.com, when I press submit it just has a pop up that list the values, but does not actually go to the results page.

Comment: I am able to go to search page from http://www.sdmlsurvey.com/search/advanced . Also comment the alert statement. That was just for demo.

Comment: For some reason it only passes to the results page only the last checkbox that is checked.

Comment: I think you will have check the server side code of the search results page because the value that is alerted is reflecting the selections appropriately.

Comment: 0
down vote
accept
First, I had to change the "," to a "|" because that is the correct syntax for ExpressionEngine. But for some reason the search will not work if there is a "|" at the end.

So for example if I select three checkboxes the output to the hidden keyword box is Aberdeen|Harrisburg|Avon| and this will not work with the search, but if I manually enter Aberdeen|Harrisburg|Avon with no "|" at the end, the search will work.

So How can I change this line to not have a "|" at the end of the keywords templateValues += checkBox.value + "|";

Comment: I am not familiar with ExpressionEngine. I am providing the HTML side of the answer for your question. Updated the post to use | for concatenation and also to remove any trailing |'s. Check it.

Comment: I am still getting the trailing |'s

Comment: :) I think its time to hit the bed now.. I added unwanted character earlier. Just try this last update. I am pretty sure it will work.

Comment: WOW! Thanks so much I never would have figured that out on my own

Comment: @Tomalak I'd like to know why people keep using them

Comment: @Tomalak I hope not :) A lazy programmer is the recipe for disaster. I think it's a combination of old habits and indifference towards ugly constructs.

Answer (score 0):

```
function removeTrailingPipe(mytext){
  mytextarray=mytext.split('|');  
  while(mytextarray[mytextarray.length-1]==''){  
    mytextarray.slice(0,mytextarray.length-1);
  }
  return mytextarray.join('|');
}

mytext='red|green|blue|yellow|';  
mytext=removeTrailingPipe(mytext);
```